# how to refactor multiple For Loops

Tags: java

I googled this question but didn't find appropriate solution in few links so thought to put it here.

Question : if we have multiple For Loop (having simple method) then how can we  refactor this scenario. In my selenium script it looks really weird to have back to back such methods.

I need that specific sequence. Method_2 can Not be executed until  Method_1  executed completely.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     Method_1();
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     Method_2();
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     Method_3();
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     Method_4();
 }
```

Consider : all methods under For loops are different.

Number of count -> n : we can consider constant for now, please let me know if it's a good idea to refactor such code or if possible then what would be solution ?

Comment: This depends on what the methods do. Since you have used abstract methods it's hard to say. Could all methods be put into one loop?

Comment: Why are you tagging Java & C# & PHP & C++?

Comment: it's programmatic question , let people throw their ideas ....why not ?

Comment: @KIKO : that's why I already mentioned those are "simple method" like specific action ....not using any where else. you may focus on original question , please.

Comment: `why not ?` Because it is annoying, and the code above is clearly not PHP.

Comment: For the one who did the latest edit to this question, How did you "figure" this is a java code? Because if you copied this exact piece of code it will compile in JAVA, C# and C++.

Comment: @mjwills It doesn’t matter if it’s php or java, it’s an algorithm question.

Comment: `Algorithm`? Pardon me, I thought it's about `refactoring` and `selenium script` and I don't know, "programmatic question"? @Pierre-AdrienMaison

Comment: You guys gave me (-5) for the conceptual questions. I am still saying language does not matter. I would like to know the ideas. Second....google it you will not find the answer of such question right away. I am helping others too by putting this question. thanks

Comment: If language doesn't matter, don't specify a language is what you should do. Specifying _multiple_ languages (some of which your code sample is not valid in) feels spammy.

Comment: Can you give us some context about what upsets you about your current code? What is your impetus for change?

Comment: sure, I will take care in future, sorry. But what about this bumpy (-5) points ? I tagged multiple language first time. having good intention to do something better for others.

Comment: The reasons for downvoting a question are: no research, not clear, or not helpful. I think the question is clear enough, but you got 3 close votes for "unclear what you're asking". So maybe that was it? As far as research goes, it depends what you search for. In this case you're trying to take your repeated code and put it in a method. The arguments to the method would be `n` and the function you want to execute. If you google for "how to pass a method as a parameter" in whatever language you're using, I guess you would find the answer. But I didn't down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is for C#, back when there was a C# tag. Not sure how this converts to java)

You can write a method that takes an integer that represents how many times you want to execute some method, and that takes an `Action` or delegate for the method to execute:

```
private static void ExecuteNTimes(int n, Action method)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        method();
    }
}
```

Then, if you have some simple methods with the same signature as in your example:

```
private static void Method_1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executed Method_1");
}

private static void Method_2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executed Method_2");
}

private static void Method_3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executed Method_3");
}

private static void Method_4()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executed Method_4");
}
```

You can execute them in your main code like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var numTimesToExecute = 3;

    ExecuteNTimes(numTimesToExecute, Method_1);
    ExecuteNTimes(numTimesToExecute, Method_2);
    ExecuteNTimes(numTimesToExecute, Method_3);
    ExecuteNTimes(numTimesToExecute, Method_4);

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: [tag:java] was picked out by someone who isn't the OP, so don't mind that tag.

Answer (score 0):

From a PHP background (which you stated in the tags initially, not sure why) this is the approach if I had to run a certain function n times across 4 functions:

**Different syntax to what you did earlier**

```
$n = 50;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) Method_1();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) Method_2();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) Method_3();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) Method_4();
```

**Different loop approach**

```
$n = 50; // per-function calls
$a = 4;  // amount of functions being called
for ($i = 1; $i <= $a * $n; $i++){
  $nm = floor($i/$n)+1;
  $fn = "Method_".$nm;
  if ($nm <= $a) $fn();
}
```

**This codeset works if you are starting from `Method_0`, has less code and the above was made up from the non-starting from 0 approaches which was creating less maintainable code**

```
$n = 50; // per-function calls
$a = 4;  // amount of functions being called
for ($i = 1; $i <= ($a * $n) -2; $i++){
  $nm = floor($i/$n);
  $fn = "Method_".$nm;
  $fn();
}
```

Tested code, works perfectly fine for the use case necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an array with your method names such as:
$functions = [ 0 => 'Method_1', 1=>'Method_2']

And then do a couple of nested loops, one for moving towards the end of the array (First method1, then method2, etc) and the inner loop can be exactly as the one you have but using call_user_func to dynamically change methods. 
PHP Docs: [Call User Func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

I personally don't see any real advantage for this unless you have a lot of methods. If you only have to do it for 4, I might as well would leave it as is....

**got confused and thought this was PHP, sorry for the references but logic in Java should be the same**

Comment: PHP devs > all. ;)

Answer (score -1):

***If*** the order or execution is unimportant, you can put all the calls in one loop since they're all called equal times

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Method_1();
    Method_2();
    Method_3();
    Method_4();
}
```

Comment: They would be executed sequentially, in the order specified by the developer. Why would the order of execution be "unimportant"? It's explicitly defined.

Comment: I need that specific sequence. Method_2 can be Not executed without Method_1, I am sorry to forgot that info in my question. But I know your solution, thanks